# How to run thin in the vps after the terminal window is closed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vps, thin

Hey guys
After several weeks of local testing, I'm now setting up a VPS, and try to run rails on it. At this point, I can open up a Terminal session and ssh to the VPS, run the thin start, then I the server is running ok, But as soon as I closed the terminal the thin is down.

How can I make thin server running in the VPS all the time?

another question how to change from test mode to production mode in rails.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demonize thin, run it with -d flag.

```
thin -d
```

Answer (score 1):

For the task at hand you will want to use a tool called Screens

Install it:

```
sudo apt-get install screen
```

Then to run it you run:

```
screen -d executable
```

To put screen to background: Ctrl+D

To recall a screen: screen -r.

You should be all good now.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really want to launch and stop thin by hand. You want it to be a daemon to be started when your system start and to be managed like any other daemons (e.g. nginx, syslog, sshd, etc.). How to do this is very distribution-dependent, but you should definitely have a look at `/etc/init.d/` or `/etc/rc.d/` and `/etc/rc.conf`.
To go in production mode within the command line you use `thin -e production`, but the preferred way should be to specify it in thin's configuration files. You should have (or create) an `/etc/thin/` folder, with one `.yml` file for each application you're deploying.